# Get actual DST savings in milliseconds

Tags: java, calendar, timezone, dst

I'm making analog clock in Java Swing. To calculate clock pointer angles I need:

1. UTC time in milliseconds which I can get with `System.currentTimeMillis()`
2. TimeZone offset
3. TimeZone DST savings.

For 2) and 3) I thought of using 
`TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset()` and `TimeZone.getDefault().getDSTSavings()`.

But `getDSTSavings()` always returns `3600000` regardless of current date is in winter/summer time.
It looks like it only checks to see if that zone is under `DST` management and if so it returns `3600000` otherwise `0`.
Is this a bug in `getDSTSavings()`?
If not then only way to get current `DST` correction in miliseconds is to use Calendar instance like: `Calendar.getInstance.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET)`?

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());        //currentZone: CET/CEST +1/+2, GMT+1:00
System.out.println("System time, " + System.currentTimeMillis()); //UTC current milis
System.out.println("Calendar time, " + cal1.getTime().getTime());   //UTC current milis
System.out.println("Calendar milis, " + cal1.getTimeInMillis());       //UTC current milis
System.out.println("Calendar Zone Offset: " + cal1.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET));
System.out.println("Calendar DST Offset: " + cal1.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET));
System.out.println("Calendar Zone Offset: " + cal1.getTimeZone().getRawOffset());
System.out.println("Calendar DST Offset: " + cal1.getTimeZone().getDSTSavings());
System.out.println("");

// Winter time, CET
cal1.set(2010, 11, 15, 14, 15, 5);
System.out.println("Calendar milis, " + cal1.getTimeInMillis()); //UTC
System.out.println("Calendar Zone Offset: " + cal1.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET)); // 3600000 correct
System.out.println("Calendar DST Offset: " + cal1.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET)); // 0 correct
System.out.println("Calendar Zone Offset: " + cal1.getTimeZone().getRawOffset()); // 3600000 correct
System.out.println("Calendar DST Offset: " + cal1.getTimeZone().getDSTSavings()); // 3600000 wrong !!!
System.out.println("");

// Summer time - CEST
cal1.set(2010, 8, 15, 14, 15, 5);
System.out.println("Calendar milis, " + cal1.getTimeInMillis()); //UTC
System.out.println("Calendar Zone Offset: " + cal1.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET)); // 3600000 correct
System.out.println("Calendar DST Offset: " + cal1.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET)); // 3600000 correct
System.out.println("Calendar Zone Offset: " + cal1.getTimeZone().getRawOffset()); // 3600000 correct
System.out.println("Calendar DST Offset: " + cal1.getTimeZone().getDSTSavings()); // 3600000 correct
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an example of how DST is used:

```
TimeZone london = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London");
System.out.println(london.getOffset(date.getTime()));
```

This will print 3600000 if Daylight Saving Time is in effect in London at the specified date. Otherwise it will print 0.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for. Offset is just zone and time dependent. Now I don't need to create new calendar instance on every tick. Instead just detect current zone when starting the clock.

final TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
final long utcTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
final long timeOffset = timeZone.getOffset(utcTime);
final long t = utcTime + timeOffset;

Answer (score 2):

The cal1 instance the you retrieve on the first line is in GMT+1 and that does not change regardless of what time / date you set on it. If you need to check the current timezone on every tick of the clock, you will need to retrieve a new Calendar instance at each tick.

As a side-note, if you're willing to add a dependency to your project - [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is a wonderful Date and Time library.